# How to make border between 2 panels in VSCode permanently visible?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make the border between panels permanently visible. At present, the border only becomes visible when I move my mouse over it.

Thanks!

(Red rectangle added for emphasis)
[image: Blue border, red highlighting added for emphasis]

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  I would like it too.  You should file an issue on this.

Comment: @Mark I requested the feature https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135005

Comment: I gave a thumps-up to your feature request.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135005

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "editorGroup.border": "#0000ff",
        "panel.border": "#0000ff",
        "sideBar.border": "#0000ff",
        "activityBar.border": "#0000ff",
        "titleBar.border": "#0000ff",
        "statusBar.border": "#0000ff"
    },
    "editorGroup.border": "#ff0000",
    "panel.border": "#ff0000",
    "sideBar.border": "#ff0000",
    "activityBar.border": "#ff0000",
    "titleBar.border": "#ff0000",
    "statusBar.border": "#ff0000"
},
```

Comment: Hehe yes, that's my issue on MS github.